flutter: Superclass has no constructor named 'CanonicalizedMap.fromEntries'
When I type flutter run in the console, I get the following error:
flutter run      
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/http_parser-4.1.0/lib/src/case_insensitive_map.dart:22:9: Error: Superclass has no constructor named 'CanonicalizedMap.fromEntries'.
      : super.fromEntries(entries, _canonicalizer);
        ^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\maven\dev\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 10s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             11.2s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

http_parser latest version is already 4.1.0
How can I fix this error?

Can you add your pubspec.lock ?

I couldn't write it here because it was too long. I added it to github gist. You can see it here: https://gist.github.com/MucahitZengin/2f153244153b3d9fd3ed7580fbc72967

The problem is fromEntries constructor for CanonicalizedMap was added in collection: 1.19.0. You can see it in changelog. With regular dependencies, it could have been enough to just up version in pubspec.yaml to something like collection: ^1.19.0.
But trick part here is that some packages from sdk (like flutter_test) depends on particular version of collection. You can not just up version in that case.
There are 2 approaches:

Downgrade http_parser. It may work if you not require specific possibilities from most recent version.

More robust way, if you ask me :) Add this block to your pubspec.yaml:


dependency_overrides:
  collection: ^1.19.0

In that case, all packages with depends on collection will be forced to use this particular version.
Hope this will help you.
